# Android custom view pass attrubute to child views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Hi i have created a custom view that extends a constraint layout below:

```
class CustomEditText : ConstraintLayout, TextWatcher {
override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle) {
    init(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle)
}

private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.my_edit_text, this)
    val a = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyEditText, defStyleAttr, 0)


    //if label text set, show it

    //if desc text set show it

    //set error text


    //else pass the other attrubute sets to the editText as per normal
    //editTextView.setAttributes????

 }
}
```

This **layout** looks like this in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/BoldTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Label Here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        style="@style/MyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/labelText"
        tools:text="description goes here" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/errorIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_verify_reg_error_bg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/descriptionText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorText"
        style="@style/MyTextViewError"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/errorIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/descriptionText"
        tools:text="Error goes here" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/errorText">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sideHintText"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.grey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="123456" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextView"
            style="@style/editTextNoBg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sideHintText"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightIcon" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i have created some custom attributes that populate the views there called `descriptionText`, `errorText` etc

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
    <attr name="leftHintText" format="string" />
    <attr name="label" format="string" />
    <attr name="description" format="string" />
    <attr name="errorText" format="string" />
    <attr name="rightActionSrc" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

When using this **custom view** I use the below:

```
<com.main.main.ui.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/titleOtherTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="5"
    app:leftHintText="name"
    app:label="firstName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleSpinner" />
```

**My question** is, How do i pass the default `android: attributes` above such as `android:maxLength`, `android:inputType` etc to the editTextView located inside my custom view?

My understanding is that only the parent view gets the `android: attributes` ie my constraintLayout but i was wondering if i can pass some of them onto the editText as i do not want to duplicate things such as `android:inputType` and `android:maxLength` when its already defined in android . I simply want to pass these on to the editText child view located in the view xml i am inflating.

Comment: The EditText does not get created by me. its automatically created in android as soon as i inflate the custom view.

Comment: Through inflating the view. You only create a view manually like that if you are programatically creating your layouts in code, not in xml

Comment: No it aint empty, i posted the full layout of that above. please check and read my code above